# how I can write this regular expression for postgresql?

Tags: regex, postgresql

how I can write this regular expression?

origin => 'fo3o321bar423ba 234 z'
result => "fo 3 o 321 bar 423 ba 234 z"

```
select regexp_replace(trim(regexp_replace(trim(regexp_replace('fo3o321bar423ba 234 z', E'([a-z]*[0-9]*)', E'\\1 ', 'g')), E'([0-9]*[a-z]*)', E'\\1 ', 'g')),'[\s.]+', ' ', 'g')
```

Comment: In pl/perl do it like `s/(?<=[a-z])(\d+)/ $1 /g`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with the following `regexp_replace`:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('fo3o321bar423ba 234 z', '([^0-9]|^)([0-9]+)(?=[^0-9]|$)', '\1 \2 ', 'g');
```

See [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d08de/1)

Result: `fo 3 o 321 bar 423 ba 234 z`

Regex matches:

- `(^|[^0-9])` - start of string or a non-digit and stores in Group 1
- `([0-9]+)` - 1 or more digits
- `(?=[^0-9]|$)` - a lookahead check if there is a non-digit or end of string right after.

The replacement string - `'\1 \2 '` - back references the captured groups 1 and 2 defined in the pattern with `(...)`.

`'g'` means we want to replace all occurrences, not just the first.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for something simple to operate.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need a function to do it. PL/Perl might be best as Perl supports regex look-behind, but here is some working JavaScript, as that's all I have:

```
create extension if not exists plv8;

create or replace function delim(s text) returns text language plv8 as $$
    var match;
    var result = [];
    while (Boolean(match = s.match(/([A-Z]+|[A-Z]?[a-z]+|[0-9]+|([^a-zA-Z0-9])+)$/))) {
        if (!match[2]) {
            result.unshift(match[1]); /* don't return non alphanumeric tokens */
        }
        s = s.substring(0, s.length - match[1].length);
    }
    return result.join(" ");
$$;


select delim('fo3o321bar423ba 234 z'); --result fo 3 o 321 bar 423 ba 234 z
```